# Compactness of Hilbert-Schmidt Operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that a certain Hilbert-Schmidt operator is compact following some exercises in Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (exercise 15 on page 112):

If $X, \mu$ is a finite measure space and $K \in L^2 (X \times X)$, define $T: L^2 (X) \rightarrow L^2 (X)$ by

$$T(f)(s) = \int_X K(s,t)f(t) d\mu (t)$$.

I think I'm supposed to show $T$ is compact following this outline:

Approximate $K$ (in some sense) by a sequence $$K_n (s,t) = \sum _{i \leq n} a^n_i (s) b^n_i (t)$$

Where $a^n_i, b^n_i  \in L^2 (X)$.  Then the operators $$T_n (f) (s) :=   \int_X K_n(s,t)f(t) d\mu (t) $$ will hopefully converge to $T$ in the operator norm.  Then the fact that every $T_n$ has finite dimensional range will imply that $T$ is compact.

The issue is that **I don't know how to find  $a^n_i$ and $b^n_i$**.  Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Try to prove "If $(X,\mu)$ is a nice measure space, and $(e_i)$ is an ONB of $L^2(X,\mu)$, then $(e_i\otimes e_j)$ is an ONB of $L^2(X\times X, \mu\times \mu)$".

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks.  That looks like what I was missing. Is there a separability issue though? As you can tell, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Also is "nice" a technical term?

Comment: Not a technical term. I just don't know if there are conditions for that to hold, and if, what exactly they are. I'm pretty sure $\sigma$-finiteness is enough, so with finiteness, you shouldn't have problems (the span of the characteristic functions of measurable rectangles is dense in $L^2$, I'm not sure if that needs $\sigma$-finiteness, measure theory isn't my forte either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the very definition of product measure space that elementary sets (i.e. set of the form $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are measurable subsets of $X$) generate $\sigma$-algebra of $X\times X$. As the consequence any measurable $C\subset X\times X$ can be "approximted" by finite disjoint unions of elementary sets. Hence so does any $K\in L_2(X\times X,\mu\times \mu)$.

P.S.

There is no finiteness issues here because the original space $X$ is of finite measure.